# How to print output of an interactive child process from parent process?

Tags: go

I am trying to get output of a interactive child process like python from the parent process. I have tried the following code to change the processes stdin to os.Stdin and stdout to os.Stdout but it isn't working. I can't see the output from the child process on the parent's terminal. Am I missing something or doing it wrong?

```golang
func main(){
  cmd := exec.Command("python")
  cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
  cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
  cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
  err := cmd.Run()
  if err != nil{
    fmt.Println("Cannot Execute cmd.")
  }
}
```

Comment: Try python -u or setting the PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable to disable output buffering. I think assigning os.Stdin should be enough to let python see that it's connected to a TTY, but try it anyway.

Comment: Setting the PYTHONUNBUFFERED did not solve the issue. I want the output to be real-time. os.Stdout only prints the result after terminating the child process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `exec.Command("python", "-i")`.

By default when running `python` not in a shell it won't enter interactive mode and won't print anything out.